# Dont update all select boxes - knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Consider the following:

```
self.selected = ko.observable();
self.selectionItems = ko.observableArray([{name: "bob"}, {name: "sally"}]);
self.containers = ko.observableArray([{name: "container 1", key:1}, {name: "container 2", key: 2}]);
```

If I have the following html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: containers">
  <div>
    <select data-bind="options: $parent.selectionItems, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name', value: $parent.selected"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then when one of the containers has an item selected all the containers update to reflect the fact that in container x you selected a name of bob.

How do I make actions like observables specific to that container element?

essentially, if I have 20 containers via the `self.containers` each container should observe it own actions. Would I make `self.selected` into an `observableArray` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind the `value` of every select to the same observable, they're all going to have the same value. You would need to have an observable in the `containers` object to store the selected.

```
self.containers = ko.observableArray([{
  name: "container 1",
  key: 1,
  selected: ko.observable()
}, {
  name: "container 2",
  key: 2,
  selected: ko.observable()
}]);
```

Alternatively, you could have an observableArray of selecteds in the parent, but that would require you to coordinate the size of your array to be the same length as `containers` and you'd have to use `$index` to get the right one; it's a clunkier option.